# C++ ! access classess via pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

the application crashes after I run it , pls help !

this header file that I make a vector that contain 2 values are X and Y.
Vector2D.h :

```
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H
#define VECTOR2D_H

class Vector2D
{
public:
    Vector2D(float x , float y ):object_x(x) , object_y(y) {}
    float getX()    {return object_x;}
    float getY()    {return object_y;}
    void setX(float x)  {object_x = x;}
    void setY(float y)  {object_y = y;}

    private:
    float object_x;
    float object_y;
};
#endif
```

This is the header file I declare a pointer to access the vector 
OMH.h

```
#include "Vector2D.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifndef OMH_H
#define OMH_H
using namespace std;
class OMH
{
public:
    OMH();
    ~OMH(void);
    void display();
    Vector2D *getMouse()
    {return mouse;}
private:
    int x;
    Vector2D *mouse;
};
#endif
```

OMH.cpp

```
OMH::OMH()
{
}


OMH::~OMH(void)
{
}
void OMH::display()
{
    mouse->setX(5);
    mouse->setY(1);
    cout<<mouse->getX();

}
```

when I build it , it succeeded

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OMH.h"
#include "Vector2D.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    OMH * object;   
    object->getMouse();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it , it show me a Error box that say :" object being used withou intilized !"
then it crashed .

Comment: `OMH * object;` is an uninitialized pointer, and usage of it is undefined but will almost certainly crash. In this case, you don't seem to need a pointer (but should `new`/`free` if you think you really need one).

Comment: You never assign anything to `mouse` either.

Comment: Also, why you're doing `OMH::~OMH(void)` in C++? `OMH::~OMH()` is enough.

Comment: Good case to use a debugger.  The debugger can help you execute statements one at a time and view the value of the variables.  Much faster than asking StackOverflow to perform a code inspection.

Answer (score 3):

`OMH* object;` creates an *uninitialized pointer*. `object` doesn't point to a `OMH` instance so when you call `getMouse()` you will incur undefined behavior. The use of pointers here isn't needed so you can just create an `OMH` object on the stack:

```
OMH object;
object.getMouse();
```

You have the same problem with `OMH::mouse`. It is a pointer that is not given a valid memory block to point to. You should question whether a pointer is really needed for that situation.

Comment: Also, `OMH`, not `OMG`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat although OMG is a better name :))

Comment: hi , it does help me , but I really need a pointer here , can you show me how can I use a pointer here ?

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is just a variable that can store an address in the memory. You need to actually create an instance of `OMH`:

```
OMH *object = new OMH;
// Do stuff
delete object;
```

Although most likely, you do no need a pointer after all and can just use an automatic variable instead:

```
OMH object;   
object.getMouse();
```

Comment: I tried OMH * object = new OMH ; it not causing crash but it doesn't print out even the object->getMouse(); that I have function to print out

Comment: @Feint13 You have the same bug in the implementation of `OMH::getMouse` (uninitialized pointer).

Comment: it Augen , thank , I fixed it by initialize it in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
OMH * object;
```

just declares a pointer to `OMH` which does not point to anything (it is default-initialized). So when you do

```
object->getMouse();
```

you get undefined behaviour (crash in your case).

You need to initialize the pointer

```
OMH* object = new OMH; // don't forget to delete
```

or better, use a smart pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<OMH> object(new OMH); // or use std::make_unique<> in C++14
```

Moreover, in the constructor `OMH::OMH()`, you probably want to initialize the pointer `mouse`, since now it looks like `mouse` does not point to anything valid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not default-initialized, but will have an *unknown value*, which means it does point to something, just not something valid for use.

Comment: @crashmstr that's what default-initialization means actually. Not the same as value-initialization. See for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization